# Construction of a SKE scheme based on a PRF family and on a MAC with UF-CMA security. Is the scheme secure?

Tags: public-key, mac, pseudo-random-function, chosen-ciphertext-attack, cmac

Consider the following construction of a SKE scheme $\Pi^*=(Enc^*,Dec^*)$ based on a PRF family $F=\{F_k:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n\}_{k\in\{0,1\}^\lambda}$ and on a MAC
$ Tag:\{0,1\}^\lambda \times \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^\lambda$ with UF-CMA security.

**Key Generation:** The key generation algorithm returns a random key $k^*=(k^{'},k^{''})$ where $k^{'},k^{''} \in \{0,1\}^\lambda$.

**Encryption:** The encryption algorirhm takes $k^*=(k^{'},k^{''})$ and $m \in \{0,1\}^n$ as input, and it returns $c^*=(r,c^{'},c^{''})$ where
$r \leftarrow^{\\\$} \{0,1\}^n, c^{'}=F_{k^{'}}(r)⊕ m $ and $c^{''}=Tag_{k^{''}}(c^{'})$.

**Decryption:** The decryption algorithm takes $k^*=(k^{'},k^{''})$ and $c^*=(r,c^{'},c^{''})$ and outputs $m=F_{k^{'}}(r)⊕ c^{'}$ if and only if $Tag_{k^{''}}(c^{'})=c^{''}$, othwrwise it outputs 0.

Prove or disprove $\Pi^*$ achieves CCA security.

---

I want to prove that $\Pi^*$ is secure, so I'm considering the following game $Game(\lambda,b)$

1. $k^*=(k^{'},k^{''}) \leftarrow^{\\\$} \{0,1\}^{2\lambda}$;
2. $(m_0,m_1) \leftarrow A^{Enc(k^*,·),Dec(k^*,·)}(1^{\lambda})$;
3. $b\leftarrow^{\\\$} \{0,1\}$;
4. $c^* \leftarrow Enc(k^*,m_b)$;
5. $b^{'} \leftarrow A^{Enc(k^*,·),Dec(k^*,·)}(1^{\lambda},c^*)$.

And I want that
$Game (\lambda,0) ≈ Game (\lambda,1)$.

---

If

- $c^{'}_b=F_{k^{'}}(r)⊕ m_b $
- $c^{''}_b=Tag_{k^{''}}(c^{'}_b)$

Since $r$ and $b$ are random and $F_{k^{'}}$ is a PRF than $c^{'}_0$ and $c^{'}_1$ have the same distribution.

Now, since $Tag_{k^{''}}$ is UF-CMA, then $Tag_{k^{''}}(c^{'}_0)$ and $Tag_{k^{''}}(c^{'}_1)$ have the same distribution too.

Hence, it is impossible to distinguish $(c^{'}_0,c^{''}_0)$ from $(c^{'}_0,c^{''}_0)$ and therefore $Game (\lambda,0) ≈ Game (\lambda,1)$.

Is that all right?

Comment: This is just encrypt-then-MAC but you don't take a MAC of the entire ciphertext. It turns out that this scheme is not CCA-secure. Your sketch considers indistinguishability of the ciphertexts, but does not account for the adversary's view of its decryption oracle.